# Select query for viewing data in specific data rang in FoxPro database

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

In foxpro database, how to write select query for viewing data in specific time range. Can anyone show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just write it as you would do with any SQL database. The only thing that differs is the parameters' syntax. For example below query retrieves all the transactions made in, say July 2020:

```
local ltFrom, ltUpTo
ltFrom = DateTime(2020,7,1)
ltUpTo = DateTime(2020,8,1) && Midnight

select * from myTable ;
   where transactionDatetime >= ?m.ltFrom and  ;
         transactionDatetime < ?m.ltUpTo ;
   into cursor crsResult ;
   nofilter
browse
```

Comment: mention select query working. thanks for prompt support.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Cetin's query for a date range query, you can also query for ranges including the time component:

```
ltFrom = DateTime(2020,8,1,0,0,0)   && midnight
ltUpTo = DateTime(2020,8,1,14,03,51) && 2:03:51 pm
*ltFrom = DateTime(2020,8,1,0,0,0)  && midnight
*ltUpTo = DateTime(2020,8,3,11,59,59) && 1 second before noon 2 days later
SELECT hostname,timestamp FROM gsm WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ?ltfrom AND ?ltupto INTO CURSOR crsResult NOFILTER ORDER BY timestamp
select * from myTable ;
   where transactionDatetime between ?m.ltFrom and ?m.ltUpTo ;
   into cursor crsResult ;
   nofilter
browse
```

There are 2 time ranges above:

1. August 1, 2020 from midnight up to 2:03:51pm
2. August 1, 2020 from midnight up to August 3, 2020, 11:59:59am (commented out)

Comment: That is not correct really. I already wrote the date time range query including times above. With a datetime range query, you wouldn't want to use BETWEEN. BETWEEN behaves as >= and <=. But you want an exclusive upper range and thus write it as >= and < (see the query in my reply). m.ltUpTo is the smallest datetime value that you want to be "excluded" not "included". That little 1 second sometimes mean much (although you don't see that, datetime values are stored as 8 byte numeric values and contain milliseconds).

Comment: Oh, okay Cetin. Thanks for the clarification. You're absolutely correct: I wasn't thinking of that "little 1 second". I was just trying to highlight that you can also use the time component (not just full days). I've always gained insight from your responses!

Comment: Sorry I was not trying to be picky. I learned that milliseconds thing the hard way many years ago, spending hours on it for debugging :) On debug all values seemed to be right (display doesn't show those milliseconds). I guess I could write a few pages article about it :) It is held as 8 bytes values in various products (ie: VFP, Windows OS file and sytem times, MS SQL server ...)  and what is funny, it is not even consistent how that 8 bytes is used between all those MS products. Thanks for the compliments.

Comment: Not picky at all! Esp. near midnight, lol! :) I have been bitten by something similar on the SQL side of things... if I remember correctly, data was been stored as a datetime and reporting was done using date or something like that. When our report looked for x=date, it wasn't taking into consideration the time component and missing everything after midnight.